# Neo4j Optional Match

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to generate an array which contains the number of messages sent from a employee to all (if any or zero if there is no communication) using OPTIONAL MATCH Clause, but its not working. I am not getting zeroes in the array when there is no communication. I am using the following query:

```
MATCH(e:Employee{key:101,div:'finance'}),(b:Employee)
OPTIONAL MATCH (e)-[r:Message]->(b)
WITH e.name as  em, r.NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES as msg 
ORDER BY msg DESC
RETURN em, COLLECT(msg) AS row
```

Here is the output:

```
Row: [31,20,12,10,8,7,7,2,2,2,2,1,1,1]
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that [collect()](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect) will collect all values **ignoring nulls**. When has no communication between two nodes the value of `msg` variable will be `null` and consequently ignored by `COLLECT()`. To fix it change your query to:

```
MATCH(e:Employee{key:101,div:'finance'}),(b:Employee)
OPTIONAL MATCH (e)-[r:Message]->(b)
WITH e.name as  em, coalesce(r.NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES,0) as msg 
ORDER BY msg DESC
RETURN em, COLLECT(msg) AS row
```

This query use the [coalesce()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-coalesce) function. This function will return the first non-null value in the list of arguments passed to it. Then, if `r.NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES` is `null` it will be replaced by zero.